# Java - Serializing a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization

I have a collection of objects that I am trying to Serialize.  Unfortunately these objects all have a reference to the controller class that holds them which also holds the threads of execution.  Whenever I try to serialize this collection I am getting an error that it can not Serialize a thread. Is there any way around this without restructuring my entire setup? I can give more details if that will be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you make the reference to the controller class [transient](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient).

Comment: That is perfect, I had never heard of that before. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You just mark the threads as `transient` to tell the serialization mechanism that these fields should not be saved along with the rest of that object's state.
So you must mark `transient` any field that either cannot be serialized or any field you do not want serialized.

Answer (score 0):

In each object in the collection the reference to the controller should be

```
private transient Controller controller = ...
```